# My Xcode keeps sending an error and I can't seem to fix it

Tags: swift

I don't know whats wrong with my code can anyone help me fix it?

[image: I don't know whats wrong with my code can anyone help me fix it?]

Comment: Start by reading the documentation for the various `UIView animate...` methods.

Comment: Also, please update your question with actual code, copy and pasted into the question. Please be sure it is formatted properly and clearly indicate what errors you are getting and where.

Comment: Please do not add images for showing the errors and code. Please read this link which will help you ask a question properly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using swift 3, you should animate like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    // You code that will be animated
}
```

You are missing the {}.